# HTML select displaying previous value in a React list of elements

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm displaying a list of `Todos` using React. Each Todo has a `category` attribute displayed as a `select` element, with a `value` as the `todo.category`. The select contains a list of `option` mapped to each category available. When I delete a Todo that has a `category` set, the next Todo displays that category, even though the Todo object itself does not have a category set. If I reload the page, the `select` switches to the default value, as should have from the beginning. Here's my implementation:

```
import React from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import actions from "../actions";
import categoriesSelector from "../reducers/categories/selectors";

const Todo = ({ todo, index }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const categories = useSelector(categoriesSelector.getCategories);

  const handleDeleteTodo = () => {
    dispatch(actions.deleteTodo(todo.id));
  };

  const handleAssignCategory = (e) => {
    const categorizedTodo = { ...todo, category: e.target.value };
    dispatch(actions.updateTodo(index, categorizedTodo));
  };


  return (
    <li>
      <label>{todo.title}</label>
      {Array.isArray(categories) && (
        <select onChange={handleAssignCategory} value={todo.category}>
          <option value="No category">No category</option>
          {categories.map(({ category }, index) => (
            <option value={category} key={index}>
              {category}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      )}
      <button onClick={handleDeleteTodo}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

**Screenshots**

List of todos, first todo has category `cate1`
[image: 3 Todos, one with category selected]

Todos:

```
    [
      {
        done: false,
        title: 'todo1',
        id: 70,
        category: 'cate1'
      },
      {
        done: false,
        title: 'todo2',
        id: 71
      },
      {
        done: false,
        title: 'todo3',
        id: 72
      }
    ],
```

After removing `todo1`:
[image: Todos after removing todo1]

`Todos`:

```
[
      {
        done: false,
        title: 'todo2',
        id: 71
      },
      {
        done: false,
        title: 'todo3',
        id: 72
      }
    ],
```

How to correctly display the "No category" value?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you should try to store the todos array in a `useState` and pass it in `useEffect` hook for it to refresh on its on. That should render your page once you delete or add any todo and the old info won't come up. for example,

```
const [todo, setTodo] = useState([{ done: false, title: 'todo2', id: 71}]);

useEffect(() => {

}, [todo])
```

Comment: I'm storing the todos in a Redux store, and when one is deleted, the reducer takes care of returning the new state, which re renders the page. As shown above, the new state of `todos` is correct. The issue seems to be related to the select somehow keeping previous value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   <button onClick={(id)=>handleDeleteTodo(id)}>Delete</button>

  const handleDeleteTodo = (id) => {
    dispatch(actions.deleteTodo(id));
  };
```

you send spasefic id and delete to do list item